# Combine three SQL update statements into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can I run these 3 update statements in one, rather than three? I could only find mysql examples for how to do this

```
update    [NoteAlertLog]
set alertmessage = NULL where alertmessage = ''

update    [NoteAlertLog]
set notes = NULL where cast([notes] as nvarchar(max)) = ''

update    [NoteAlertLog]
set externalnotes = NULL where cast(externalnotes as nvarchar(max)) = ''
```

I have tried like this but get a syntax error:

```
update    [NoteAlertLog]
set alertmessage = NULL where alertmessage = ''
,set notes = NULL where cast([filenotes] as nvarchar(max)) = ''
,set externalnotes = NULL where cast(externalnotes as nvarchar(max)) = ''
```

And I have tried without the `set`:

```
update    [NoteAlertLog]
set alertmessage = NULL where alertmessage = ''
,notes = NULL where cast([filenotes] as nvarchar(max)) = ''
,externalnotes = NULL where cast(externalnotes as nvarchar(max)) = ''
```

Comment: You can do it, but the three independent queries are simpler.

Comment: Hmm ok. It was just to suppress the `x rows affected` appearing three times, which i have to account for in another area of my stored procedure. If there was just one count for the entire update, it'd be easier

Comment: That problem is more easily solved by setting `NOCOUNT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `case` expressions:

```
update    [NoteAlertLog]
set alertmessage = case when alertmessage = '' then NULL else alertmessage end,
    notes = case when cast([notes] as nvarchar(max)) = '' then NULL else notes end,
    externalnotes = case when cast(externalnotes as nvarchar(max)) = '' then NULL else externalnotes end

where alertmessage = ''
   or cast([notes] as nvarchar(max)) = ''
   or cast(externalnotes as nvarchar(max)) = ''
```

The `where` clause can be skipped, but I'd keep it to keep transaction size down.